# Nagios & Check_MK certain notifications?

Tags: notifications, monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I run nagios3 on a debian system and I want to separate notifications.

Now all notifications get sent to e-mail and SMS. What I want is that when a certain service gives either a warning or critical it gets send to SMS.

So let's say I have service A, B, C and D. I want to be notified by SMS if either service A or C fails. But I don't want to get notified by SMS if either service B or D fails.

I read something about Check_MK having a flexible notifications option. Can I use Check_MK for this or is Nagios itself capable of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I don't use plain Nagios I can't help you with Nagios but check_mk is capable of doing that.
With check_mk you can define separate notifications for defined services or hosts by blacklisting or whitelisting. You can also define timeperiodes and escalations. Take a look at: https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_flexible_notifications.html
For Nagios I'm pretty sure that is capable of doing that too.